# In Play framework how to Auto Increment the primary key field by extending GenericModel in Model class?

Tags: hibernate, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am trying to autoincrement the primary key field but it is not incrementing using GenericModel in Models Below is my code.

```
package models;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import play.data.validation.Required;
import play.db.jpa.GenericModel;
@Entity
public class Test extends GenericModel{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column(name="uniqueOppId" ,nullable =false)
    public Long id;
    @Required
    public String name;


}
```

Comment: Is any body there to answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a simple number ID than use the annotation:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
```

It starts with 1 and auto-increments from there with every new entity. The ID generator you are using generates a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

Comment: Thank you your answer is helpful to me