# JPA/Java Play new row is created on update

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework

I am working with some existing code (Java Play 1.44/JPA) and I am trying to explain/modify some behavior.
My classes() have the following setup.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ATable")
public class AEntity extends GenericModel
{
    
    @Id
    @Required
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    /**
     * Required fields
     */
    @Required
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    private BEntity bEntity;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "BTable")
public class BEntity extends GenericModel
{
    
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "bEntry")
    private String bEntry;

   
    public Integer getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    
}
```

Anytime I make any changes to the BEntity, a new row is introduced into the corresponding table. I would like to understand why. And change this behavior if possible , so that the row is updated instead.

Comment: Can you provide the code where you try to update the `BEntity`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the `updatable = false`   attribute.

Try this for example :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
public Integer id;
```

Also see this post [In Play framework how to Auto Increment the primary key field by extending GenericModel in Model class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32091532/in-play-framework-how-to-auto-increment-the-primary-key-field-by-extending-gener) for further information.